# Woocommerce: Showing Shipping Cost next to the Price in Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show the shipping cost of each product next to its price in the product page of a Woocommerce store. I'm working with shipping classes.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I would need to loop over all products and call this function to add the costs like: 14,99€ + 4,99 Shipping.

```
<?php

function ek_add_shipping_cost_to_price_tag( $price ) {

    $price .= " + 4,99€";
    return $price;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'ek_add_shipping_cost_to_price_tag' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'ek_add_shipping_cost_to_price_tag' );
?>
```

Seems like there is no data to show since Woocommerce is calculating the costs later in the checkout page?

Comment: This would only really work if you are using Flat Rate shipping costs.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: While you have included code, this is _not really an attempt_ to solve your own problem.  Voting to close.  (NOTE: This is NOT a simple problem to solve, you've asked a very, very big question, and shown zero effort to solve it yourself).